# Not able to find Mongo Shell in MongoDB36

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

have installed MongoDB Server 36 , however unable to find the Mongo Shell utility 
Can someone point me where to find the same or how to create or access db without Mongo Shell will also be helpfull ?

Comment: The MongoDB server must be started and running before you can use (or connect to) the mongo shell. Mongo shell is installed as part of the MongoDB server (for example, in your MongoDB installation the shell program can be found at (on Windows)
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongo.exe). Also see the documentation on [mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/index.html). Here is another way to access the MongoDB database: [compass](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 10 try doing this:
Your MongoDb shell should be at `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongo.exe` but you must add this path as environment variable in order to make it work on the windows terminal.

Search `env` and enter `Edit the system environment variables` as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuaHE.png).

Then click the `Environment Variables` button as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DsuQ.png).

In the following window add the path where your `mongo.exe` is (As commented previously it should be at `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin`). More details about the environtment variables [here](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/08/31/how-to-change-environment-variables-on-windows-10/).

Accept the changes and now you must make two folders where MongoDB will store some files. On the root of the unit where de database will be created (let's suppose `C:\`) make a folder named `data` that contains another folder named `db`. The resultant route must be like this: `C:\data\db`

Now you should be able to run the `mongo` and `mongod` commands on the Windows terminal.